EEPROM M93C66 SPI Based
The M93C66 EEPROM have a 16 bit organization. Does this mean we have to send the instructions 16 bit format or 8 bit format?

Neither.
You must send the opcodes according to the protocol in the data sheet.
Reading or writing an 8-bit byte or 16-bit word requires a transaction that is not a multiple of 8 or 16 clock cycles, so it is not compatible with byte-oriented SPI bus.

In the datasheet it was not mentioned properly, like for 16 bit memory organization we should use 16 bit instructions and for the 8 bit memory organization, we should use 8 bit  instructions. Anyway we used 16 bit instructions for the 16 bit memory organization and we got write and read.
